# How do I change a property in Javascript with media query?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS. I'm trying to use media queries with Vanilla JavaScript. I'm trying to design a Slider to my webpage. I'm using Swiper.js. This is my JS code:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
 
// Optional parameters
   loop: true,
   slidesPerView: 3,
   spaceBetween: 30,

// If we need pagination
pagination: {
  el: '.swiper-pagination',
  clickable: true,
},

// Navigation arrows
navigation: {
  nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
  prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
}, });
```

I want to modify the `slidesPerView` property value to 1 with media-query max-width of 750px. I tried this way:

```
var media = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 750px)");
mediaSlider(media);
media.addListener(mediaSlider);

function mediaSlider(media) {
    if(media.matches) {
        mySwiper.slidesPerView = 1;
    }
}
```

This method is not working. Kindly help me to find out where I've missed something.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always suggested to read the documentation properly. I'd made the same mistake again. Swiper.js provides an option to add responsive breakpoints. I modified my code like this in order to work it out.

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {

  // Optional parameters
    loop: true,
    slidesPerView: 1,
    spaceBetween: 30,

    breakpoints: {
       750: {
           slidesPerView: 3,
       },
   },
```

Answer (score 0):

its called `addEventListener`. There is only 1 event. Its called `change`

```
let media = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 750px)");

function mediaSlider(media) {
  if (media.matches) {
    mySwiper.slidesPerView = 1;
  }
}

media.addEventListener("change", mediaSlider);
```